# Prisma nestjs type error when creating a data using user model

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, backend, prisma

I am using nestjs together with prisma 4.9.0. I already have my prisma service with prisma module configured to be a global.

I have no problem when finding users. But when it comes to creating a user I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
```

on `await this.prisma.user.create({data: data});`

Here's my prisma schema

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  userID   String @id @unique @default(cuid())
  email    String @unique
  password String
}
```

Here's my nestjs create user service

```
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma/prisma.service';
import * as argon from 'argon2';

export class CreateUserService {
  constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) { }
    
  async execute(email: string, password: string) {

    const hashedPassword = await argon.hash(password);

    const data = {
      email: 'test@test.test',
      password: 'testpassword'
    };

    console.log(email, hashedPassword);

    const newUser = await this.prisma.user.create({
      data: data
    });

    return user;
  }
}
```

Here's my UserController.ts

```
import { Controller, Post, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserService, RetrieveUserService } from './services';

@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  constructor(
    private createUserService: CreateUserService,
    private retrieveUserService: RetrieveUserService
  ) { }

  @Get()
  async retrieve() {
    try {
      return await this.retrieveUserService.execute();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  @Post()
  async create(@Body('email') email: string, @Body('password') password: string) {
    try {
      return await this.createUserService.execute(email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my Prisma Module

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';

@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [PrismaService],
  exports: [PrismaService],
})
export class PrismaModule {}
```

Here is my PrismaService

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleDestroy, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config/dist';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService
  extends PrismaClient
  implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy
{
  constructor(config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      datasources: {
        db: {
          url: config.get('DATABASE_URL'),
        },
      },
    });
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }
  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.$disconnect();
  }
}
```

Here is my app module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { PrismaModule } from './prisma/prisma.module';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';



@Module({
  imports: [
    // App Modules
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    PrismaModule,

    // Custom Modules
    UserModule,
    ...
    ...

  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I tried to re create the project, change the model name to customer, delete the database and migrations. Still the problem persist.

This is my first time encountering this type of error on prisma's model and I really tried everything.

Thanks in advance for any help or advise.

Comment: How do you instantiate CreateUserService?

Comment: On my user.controller.ts via constructor

Comment: this.prisma is undefined so are you sure you pass a valid `PrismaService` to the CreateUserController?

Comment: I did a triple checked, please correct me if i'm wrong. If I'am passing a wrong prisma service, the GetUserService wouldn't run properly or I will get an Type Error also but for me it didn't, and nestjs will output an error if I imported an instance of prisma that was not in the app module.

Comment: Do you have a link to a repo I can look at? Its kinda hard to tell from the parts you've sent here

Comment: Sorry the repo is private due to company policy. However, I edited the question and added prisma service, prisma module and app module that correspond with prisma and the user.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it,

I created a new nestjs project and imported a prisma package dedicated to nestjs called [nestjs-prisma](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-prisma)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was able to solve it by doing

```
constructor(
    @Inject(PrismaService)
    private readonly prisma: PrismaService,
) {}
```

in the `users.service.ts` so you explicitly have to add the `@Inject()` decorator.